# Prove: $\phi$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces if and only if $\det(M_{C,B}(\phi))\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $V, W$ be finite-dimensional $F$-vector spaces of dimension $n> 0$ and let $\phi: V \to W$ be a linear mapping

*Prove:*
For every ordered basis $B$ of $V$ and every ordered basis $C$ of $W$: $ϕ$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces if and only if
$$\det(M_{C,B}(\phi))\neq 0.$$

I understand this question but I can't get anywhere with the proof. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $\phi$ is linear mapping, in other words, it is a homomorphism. So what you need to do is just prove that it is bijection.

If $\phi$ is isomorphism then $\phi$ is bijection, so that transformation matrix is regular. So its determinant is non-zero.

Now for the other implication, we know that matrix is regular, hence our mapping is bijection.

Comment: What is a regular matrix in this context?

Comment: Thanks, I alreay edited it.